# Connect to DB2 using python

Tags: python, database, db2, connect

I'm using python 2.7 and I want to connect to a DB2 database and insert data into it. Here is what I did so far :

```
import sqlalchemy
from sqlalchemy import *
import ibm_db_sa

db2 = sqlalchemy.create_engine('ibm_db_sa://user:pswd@localhost:50001/prm')
metadata = MetaData()
users = Table('users', metadata, 
Column('user_id', Integer, primary_key = True),
Column('user_name', String(16), nullable = False),
Column('email_address', String(60), key='email'),
Column('password', String(20), nullable = False)
)
metadata.bind = db2
metadata.create_all()
users_table = Table('users', metadata, autoload=True, autoload_with=db2)
users_table
```

The problem is when I execute the code above I get this the following error :

```
ProgrammingError: (ProgrammingError) ibm_db_dbi::ProgrammingError: [IBM][CLI Driver]
SQL1042C  An unexpected system error occurred.  SQLSTATE=58004\r SQLCODE=-1042 None None
```

Can anyone help me to figure this out ?

Answer (score 2):

Although problem solved I write my bit as it might be helpful for someone.

In my case LD_LIBRARY_PATH and all lib folders were OK.

Reinstalling ibm_db and ibm_db_sa in virtualenv solved issue.

```
pip uninstall ibm_db ibm_db_sa
pip install ibm_db ibm_db_sa
```

My guess is that ibm_db was installed before there was a DB2 driver installed in system (maybe someone ignored errors/warning).

It's good to check if you can connect to database with db2cli first

```
db2cli execsql -connstring "DATABASE=database_name;HOSTNAME=db_host;PORT=50000;PROTOCOL=TCPIP;UID=db_user;PWD=db_pass;"

> select 'db_name' from sysibm.sysdummy1
```

Comment: I tried following the official docs, installing with easy_install... big mistake. pip just works

Answer (score 0):

I finally got it to work by adding `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` to environment variables with the value : `<YOUR_DB2_HOME>\SQLLIB\lib`. It works perfectly now.

Comment: It looks like you're not properly setting up your application environment.  You should be sourcing `<YOUR_DB2_HOME>/sqllib/db2profile`, which will set `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` and other necessary variables.

Comment: I looked for `db2profile` directory but I found none ! Another question, why did it work if I didn't set the variable correctly ?